# Collect list of strings to map with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Could someone suggest how could I transform list like `["bla", "blabla", "blablabla"]` to map like `{"bla" : 3, "blabla" : 6, "blablabla" : 9}` with words stands for keys and values stands for words lengths?

I do something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map =  list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), String::length));
```

but have no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `Collectors.toMap`. And make sure your stream is `distinct()`, otherwise you'll get an exception if you have duplicates in `list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost correct with `groupingBy`, but the second parameter of that is a `Collector`, not a `Function`. Thus I used `toMap`.

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of("bla", "blabla", "blablabla").distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length));
```

Comment: It works with M. Prokhorov's suggestion about distinct. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do something so complicated.
Here is an example code:

```
...
... 

List<String> ll= // the list of words that you have.
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();// or any other kind of map you want to create

for(String s:ll){
    map.put(s,s.length());
}
```

Now you have a `map` that satisfies your requirement.

Comment: It definitely works, but I'd like to solve it with streams in more accurate manner.